# Restricted access for usercontrol by role

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-roles, asp.net-authorization

is possible to limit access for particular usercontrol for particular role?

I have page (default.aspx) that load (also) info.ascx

I wanto to restricted access to info.ascx and display a message like 'unauthorized' where he was to be loaded.

thanks!

Comment: See the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433305/how-can-i-limit-asp-net-control-actions-based-on-user-role. Some of them should be helpful for usercontrols also.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inbuilt in ASP.Net. You would have to implement your own access control using the Role providers and Custom user controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="user1, user2"/>
    <deny users=”?”/>
</authorization>
```

This article may help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301324/Authorization-in-ASP-NET

Comment: I tried this for a usercontrol(ascx file) and it didn't work.